# Fullcalendar events all showing at the current datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, ef-database-first

I'm new to this, so please bear with me. I'll do my best to provide as much information as possible.

I have a system which is using Entity Framework 6.1.1, jQuery UI (Combined Library) 1.11.1, and ASP.Net MVC 5.1.2 Database First. I have implemented FullCalendar version 2.0.4 by Adam Shaw, into my project which has to read events from the database and display it on the calendar. The way I have coded it is mainly for testing purposes before I use it properly, so I haven't really adhered to any naming conventions. I have searched through many websites looking for answers and I haven't found any so far.

I am having a couple of problems with this though, but I'm not sure if I should ask both here or separate them into different threads. Firstly, all my events seem to be showing at the exact current date and time. For example, if I have event A which should show on 2014/08/24 and event B which should show on 2014/08/26, as stated in the database, when I run the application, they would all show at 20:01 2014/08/27 (the time i just typed out that text).

Secondly, my events aren't draggable or droppable at all. See below for the code.

This code is in my Model Class:

```
public partial class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        this.Bookings = new HashSet<Booking>();
        this.EventTags = new HashSet<EventTag>();
    }

    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventDays { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> EventStart { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> EventEnd { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> EventDuration { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NumberOfEmployees { get; set; }
    public string EventLocation { get; set; }
    public string EventDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EventRating { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionnaireID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EventDateCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EventDateUpdated { get; set; }
    public string EventSupplier { get; set; }
    public string EventPicture { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public virtual Questionnaire Questionnaire { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EventTag> EventTags { get; set; }
}
```

The dates that I am pointing to in the database is "EventDateCreated" and "EventDateUpdated". I am using "EventDateCreated" as "start" and "EventDateUpdated" as "end".

---

This is the code that is in my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetSchedules() {

        var calendarObjects = new List<object>();
        double start;
        double end;


        foreach (var item in db.Events)
        {


            start = ToUnixTimestamp(Convert.ToDateTime(item.EventDateCreated));
            end = ToUnixTimestamp(Convert.ToDateTime(item.EventDateUpdated));

            calendarObjects.Add(new
            {
                id = item.EventID,
                title = item.EventName,
                Start = start,
                End = end,
                allDay = false
            });

        }
        return Json(calendarObjects.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

private static long ToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date)
    {
        var ts = date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
        return (long)Math.Truncate(ts.TotalSeconds);
    }
```

The code shown here is looping through the database class Events, and getting all the event details. "EventDateCreated" and "EventDateUpdated" is sent to the method "ToUnixTimestamp" which converts the date into a UnixTimestamp, which then goes back to the "GetSchedules" method and assigns those dates to the "calendarObjects" list. Once all the details are assigned, it goes to the "return" code to send it to the view, which will then render the details on the calendar. Up to that "return" code, when hovering over the "calendarObjects.ToArray()", it shows all three events in my database, with all their details, including the different dates for each event.

---

This is the code in my Index view:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function (e) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'month',

            allDaySlot: false,
            timeFormat: 'H:mm',
            editable: true,
            disableDragging: false,
            droppable: true,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                createEvent(date);
            },
            events: "/Events/GetSchedules",


        });

    });

    </script>
```

Finally, the details are sent to this view, the Index view, which then renders the calendar. However, as mentioned, all the events are shown on the same day at exactly the same time as when i ran the application as shown in the link below:

[Calendar View](http://pho.to/6uuhO)

Why aren't the events showing on their respective dates, and why can't I drag and drop them?

Comment: Shouldn't `ts.TotalSeconds` be `ts.TotalMilliseconds`?

Comment: @Shoe I tried that now and they're all still displaying at the exact same date and time as mentioned above, so it's not that :)

Comment: Well there's several issues here, one of which is that no matter what month you're on, you will get the same result set. FullCalendar sends the `start` and `end` for the view, you need to take those passed parameters and find which events lie on them.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think that those parameters are necessary. I took them out because the controller method must read my database for the events, so I don't really see the purpose of using the "start" and "end" parameters. Also, when I did put those parameters in, then when running the application, it would never hit the "GetSchedules" method, so the events wouldn't show at all.

Comment: Think about it this way. The calendar view shows August 01 - August 31. If you have events that are from June they won't fit on your calendar. That was the purpose of those parameters. They tell you what range the calendar view is looking at.

Comment: I added the parameters into the GetSchedule method, but then when running the application, it didn't hit the GetSchedule method. Therefore on the Index View where the calendar is, in the javascript at the point that reads "events: "/Events/GetSchedules"", I had to pass random numbers for start and end for it to hit the method, like this, "events: "/Events/GetSchedules/?start=123456789&end=135792468"". I don't know what implications this will have on the events, but even when doing that, all the events are still showing up at the current date and time

Comment: What were the types on the parameters you put on your action? It should be `DateTime start, DateTime end`. The parameters are passed as date strings, not longs

Comment: In the GetSchdules method, I added "DateTime start" and "DateTime end" as parameters, and it runs the method but it still shows all the events at the current date and time. However, when using a breakpoint, somehow it's passing random dates into those parameters, so "start = 2014/07/27" and "end = 2014/09/07", and I don't have those dates anywhere in my system, but regardless of those dates, the events still show up at the current date and time

Comment: Those aren't random dates. Look at your calendar view. The calendar starts at 7/27/14 and ends at 9/7/14. That means you need to return events between those dates.